# drop downlist value keep changing after selectedIndexChange

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have two dropdown list named dl_bankName,dl_branch and a textbox named txt_bankCode.dl_bankName will be filled on pageLoad and dl_branch will get filled on the selectedIndexChange of dl_bankName and txt_bankCode will be filled on the selectedIndexChange of dl_branch. dl_bankName is filled and the selected value is retained even after postBack but dl_branch name is changed to the first value when we select other values.

my sample code is given below

HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dl_bankName" runat="server" Width="230px" 
Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="dl_bankName_SelectedIndexChanged">    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="dl_BranchName" Width="230px" Height="22px"  runat="server" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="dl_BranchName_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt_IfscMicr" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txt_IfscMicr" runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#FF5050" />
```

CODE

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                       
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {                               
        filldl_bankName();                  
    }            
}

protected void dl_bankName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    if (dl_BranchName.DataSource == null)
    {
        filldl_BranchName();  
    }                                            
    txt_IfscMicr.Text = "";             
}

protected void dl_BranchName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filltxt_IfscMicr();
}

 protected void filldl_bankName()
    {

                string query = "select '--Select--' as bank_name,'0' as bank_code from DUAL union all  select distinct(bank_name),bank_code from em_bank_details ";        
                dl_bankName.DataSource = GetDt(query);
                dl_bankName.DataTextField = "bank_name";
                dl_bankName.DataValueField = "bank_code";
                dl_bankName.DataBind();                                           
    }

    protected void filldl_BranchName()
    {           
            string query = "select '--Select--' as branch_name,'0' as bank_code from DUAL union all  select distinct(branch_name),bank_code from em_bank_details where bank_name='" + dl_bankName.SelectedItem.Text + "'";                
            dl_BranchName.DataSource = GetDt(query);
            dl_BranchName.DataTextField = "branch_name";
            dl_BranchName.DataValueField = "bank_code";
            dl_BranchName.DataBind();

    } 

    protected void filltxt_IfscMicr()
    {
          string query = "select distinct(branch_code),bank_code from em_bank_details where bank_name='" + dl_bankName.SelectedItem.Text + "' and branch_name='" + dl_BranchName.SelectedItem.Text + "'";     
            txt_IfscMicr.Text = GetDt(query).Rows[0]["branch_code"].ToString();                       
    }
```

Comment: try javascript onchange event to call your function

Comment: Whats the point here to set `dl_BranchName.Enabled = false;` first and then `dl_BranchName.Enabled = true ;` ?

Comment: @mmushtaq i've edited the code

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed i'm not that good in javascript but i will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by commenting the code line

```
 dl_BranchName.DataValueField = "bank_code";
```

in the function **filldl_BranchName()** . The **bank_code** was all same for all the  **branch_name** maybe that's what cause the issue .Now everything is working as per my requirement.